# Setting src and background for FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, floating-action-button

When I use background and src in android.support.design.FloatingActionbutton it is not set correctly. Instead it is displayed as

[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/pink"
android:src="@drawable/ic_action_barcode_2"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
```

but when I use ImageView it appears correctly as

[image]

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/pink"
android:src="@drawable/ic_action_barcode_2"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
```

why is FloatingActionButton is not displayed correctly? What should I change in my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Floating action button's background does not need to be changed, you just apply a tint and then add your icon as usual

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    ...
    app:backgroundTint="@color/ic_action_barcode_2"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

This provides you with a round button still but in the colour you desire.
In this case the `app` namespace is used for the support library features:

`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: thanks for pointing out the app namespace. Saved my hair from falling out.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the similar problem. I tried to set src or background of FloatingActionButton, but couldn't fill the button by src. following code solved problem for me.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    .
    .
    .
    android:background="@drawable/round_icon"
    android:backgroundTintMode="src_over">
```