# Can an image be used in FloatingActionButton?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I want to use an image as background of a `FloatingActionButton`.

I know that the default background color which is `colorAccent` and we can change it easily. But what about the image as its background ?

If I can then how?

Pictorial explanation will always be appreciated.

Comment: Yes it can. this is already asked before and the answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036656/setting-src-and-background-for-floatingactionbutton)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

Answer (score 4):

In xml you can set like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="mini" />
```

and in java file you can set like this:

```
  ImageView iconFAB = new ImageView(this);
        iconFAB.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_new);

        //set the appropriate background for the main floating action button along with its icon
        mFAB = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
                .setContentView(iconFAB)
                .setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.selector_button_pink)
                .build();
```

here is selector_button_pink.xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_action_red_touch" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_action_red" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
</selector>
```