# Background drawable does not fill floating action button

Tags: android, android-drawable, floating-action-button

I have FAB and trying to fill a drawable(round_drawable.xml) to my entire fab but the drawable appears currently as in the top left corner as shown here,

[image]

I tried a solution from [Setting src and background for FloatingActionButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036656/setting-src-and-background-for-floatingactionbutton)  but it did not work, added most attributes from other sources but neither `scaleType, src, background` did not work.

How do I get to fill the FAB with the round_drawable ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"

        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/round_drawable"
        android:backgroundTintMode="src_atop"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**round_drawable.xml**

`@drawable/right` is a png image of right arrow.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="50dp"
            android:shape="oval">

            <corners android:radius="10dp" />

            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:endColor="#D425B5"
                android:startColor="#EBF928" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/right" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: your code  working fine for me [check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfx4m.png)

Comment: @NileshRathod What is the problem in mine then ? Support library ?? Or something else ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add this line in you `dimen.xml` file

```
<dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">56dp</dimen>
```

**NOTE :** `56dp` is default size of FAB buttom

- Default - 56dp
- mini - 40dp
- custom - whatever you have specified in `fabCustomSize`

**TIP :** use `app:fabCustomSize` rather giving custom height width to FAB button.

**Example**

in your layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/white"

    <!--inmprtent-->
    app:fabCustomSize="100dp"

    android:src="@drawable/round_drawable"
    android:backgroundTintMode="src_atop"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

now create `dimens.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">100dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

keep your `round_drawable.xml` as it is and you are good to go

**Result**

[image]

cheers..

Comment: Couldn't get the drawable to cover fab the drawable not appears in bottom left.

Comment: give height and width of FAB button `wrap_content` and use `app:fabCustomSize="100dp"` and use this for your dimens.xml `<dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">100dp</dimen>`. i am sure it will work

Comment: have you created dimens file?

Comment: Yes I have created but I will have to set `app:fabCustomSize="56dp"` to get your output 100dp looks like this https://imgur.com/DWxqKyc

Comment: change it to 100dp as your fabCustomSize is 100dp, see example i have provided in my answer.. it is exactly what you need.

Comment: `change it to 100dp as your fabCustomSize is 100dp` for this the result is https://imgur.com/DWxqKyc got it ? Inorder to bring it as per your screenshot I will have to set fabCustomSize to 56dp...Hope you are clear of what I am saying

Comment: awesome happy to help.. please accept answer if it is helpful

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to give specific size to FAB.And it won't require background drawable also for any specific color. It has attribute **fabSize** in which you can pass predefined sizes like **mini(40dp), normal(56dp)**. And still if you want to add size remove sizes from drawable `<item>` tag. That tag actually making your drawable small.

check this sample code for creating Fab with image in center

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fbtn_addNotification"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_16"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_16"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_28dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:borderWidth="@dimen/margin_0"
            app:elevation="@dimen/margin_8"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="@dimen/margin_5" />
```

It will look like this. Hope it will help...

[image]

Comment: @GeekDroid Those attribute I have used to display FAB in bottom in relative layout so you can remove them if don't find it helpful. It has noting to do with your drawable position.

Comment: Yes I know I was discussing and looking at your code but was doing it fast,anyways I had to discuss a lot and finally my prob solved..You can go through the comments in the above and see how discussion helped me..

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer of 2019 with androidX:

Dependency : `implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'`

**XML:**

```
<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style">

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_langauge_translation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_language_icon"
        app:fab_size="normal"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:fab_title="" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_facebook_msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_fb_icon"
        app:fab_size="normal"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        app:fab_colorNormal="#0184FF"
        app:fab_colorPressed="#0184FF"
        app:fab_title="" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_whats_msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_whatsapp_icon"
        app:fab_colorNormal="#4EC248"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        app:fab_size="normal"
        app:fab_colorPressed="#4EC248"
        app:fab_title="" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_email_icon"
        app:fab_colorNormal="#848484"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        app:fab_colorPressed="#848484"
        app:fab_size="normal"
        app:fab_title="" />

</com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: That's awesome, how to change the colour of + and x of the floating action menu? Is it possible to replace it with any image/icon?

Comment: It's quite long time to create and right now I don't have this code so try with yourself now. I'll check and let you know later.

Comment: I tried, but I couldn't do it. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I used this code and it worked:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@android:color/transparent"
      />
```

and in the dimens.xml file:
  `<dimen name="design_fab_image_size" tools:override="true">40dp</dimen>`

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in you style.xml file

```
<style name="FullImageFloatingButton" parent="Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton">
    <item name="fabSize">normal</item>
    <item name="maxImageSize">56dp</item>
</style>

<style name="FullImageMiniFloatingButton" parent="Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton">
    <item name="fabSize">mini</item>
    <item name="maxImageSize">40dp</item>
</style>
```

Use **FullImageFloatingButton** for normal FloatingButton and **FullImageMiniFloatingButton** for mini FloatingButton.